# Objective-c: landscape orientation only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I want the device supports only landscape orientation. On iPhones all work fine. But iPad supports portrait too. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: you are select device universal?

Comment: I select iPad  and landscape it is work but how I use my app on iPhones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the iPad from `Devices` and check `Landscape Left` & `Landscape Right` only like this image.

[image]

Comment: After saving setting set `Devices` back to `Universal`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand , you can try with this code into any of  view controller.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: It's been removed since iOS 6.1. Instead modern apps should use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and such.